# PHP - Removing <?php ?> tags from a string

Tags: php, string, tags, eval

What's the best way to remove these tags from a string, to prepare it for being passed to eval() ?

for eg. the string can be something like this:

```
<?php
  echo 'hello world';
  ?>
  Hello Again
  <?php

  echo 'Bye';
?>
```

Obviously str_replace won't work because the two php tags in the middle need to be there (the the 1st and the last need to be removed)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It smells like a bad idea.

Comment: The answer is you do not use `eval`. ;) (Only 25% joking actually.)

Comment: I used eval once, puppies died, true story.

Comment: trust me, this is for a very legitimate reason :)

Comment: a textarea that allows the site administrator to add/modify stuff in the current theme.

Comment: you can try tokenizing then removing it you know? ;)

Comment: eval() is evil.. it can lead to all kinds of vulnerabilities as you don't know if it is scrubbing variables it uses; accessing things on the filesystem, web, etc; doing things with the session or cookies; or killing puppies. Bad.

Comment: @CaseySoftware that last one made me laugh

Comment: People, **eval() is not evil**. While it needs to be used with caution, it *is* a useful PHP function that is ideal for certain cases

Comment: For example, `eval()` would be ideal if you were letting users add PHP code snippets from a web interface to be run on the site. (Of course, only admin users would be allowed to access the interface.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a bad idea, but if you want the start and end ones removed you could do

```
$removedPhpWrap = preg_replace('/^<\?php(.*)(\?>)?$/s', '$1', $phpCode);
```

This *should* do it (not tested).

Please tell me also why you want to do it, I'm 95% sure there is a better way.

Comment: what about php without the last '?>' ? :P

Comment: Read this answer here before using above solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/589909

Comment: @brenjt So *parsing* HTML with regex and matching PHP opening and closing tags are the same thing? TIL.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, you wouldn't want to pass a function to eval.
If you're wishing to just remove the tags, string_replace would do the job just fine, however you might be better off using a regex.

`preg_replace(array('/<(\?|\%)\=?(php)?/', '/(\%|\?)>/'), array('',''), $str);`

This covers old-asp tags, php short-tags, php echo tags, and normal php tags.

Comment: I think he only wants the start and end ones removed, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Yep, I didn't see that. I thought he was having trouble with different kinds of tags.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
eval("?> $string_to_be_evald <?");
```

which would close the implicit tags and make everything work.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use regex; PHP provides functions for removing characters from the beginning or end of a string. `ltrim` removes characters from the *beginning* of the string, `rtrim` from the *end* of the string, and `trim` from both ends.

```
$code = trim ( $code );
$code = ltrim( $code, '<?php' );
$code = rtrim( $code, '?>' );
```

The first `trim()`  removes any leading or trailing spaces that are present in the siting. If we omitted this and there was whitespace *outside* of the PHP tags in the string, then the `ltrim` and `rtrim` commands would fail to remove the PHP tags.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the `<? ?>`-tags can be present several times in the file, not just at the beginning and end. Actually, if you look at his sample, there are two sets of tags in there. So regex is probably the most viable solution here.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren The functions I've used only removes PHP tags from the beginning or end of the string; not just anywhere in the string. You can read more about these functions at the links I've included in my answer

Comment: And if you do that, someone can sneak a third set of tags in the middle of the string and still do bad stuff, so this really isn't a good recommendation for the askers case.

Comment: Huh? If you read the OP's comments, he says that **only the administrator** can edit what is passed to `eval()`. Anyway, how exactly would a third set of tags be bad?

Comment: Plus, the regex method suggested here doesn't work if the string has a newline after the closing `?>` tag, or an leading space in front of the first `<?php` tag (or any other whitespace surrouding those tags)

Comment: The second parameter to `trim()` and related is a *character pool*. So you wouldn't need to specify `<?php` *and* `<?` as the first one would strip the latter.

Comment: @alex I know that `trim()` works that way, but is it the same for `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`?

Comment: @bungeshea As far as the documentation goes.